# Routing with suffix .php / parameter

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working on converting an old API to a API based on Laravel, the problem i'm facing is that I have to add a compatibility mode, so old requests won't stop to work, however i couldn't make it work using laravel routes.

Old API pattern:

```
domain.com/getinfo.php?name=YourName
```

On Laravel:

```
domain.com/getinfo/YourName
```

Therefore, how could I add some compatibility routes? I tried something like:

```
 Route::get('getinfo.php?name={name}', 'controller@function');
```

Do anyone have an idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try this: `Route::get('getinfo', 'Controller@myFunction');` in `Controller` ```...myFunction(Request $request) { return DB::table(...)->...->where('name', $request->name; }```

Comment: This might help you

 `$suffix = '.test';
 Route::get('article/edit/{name?}'.$suffix, ['uses' => 'ArticleController@edit', 'as' => 'Edit']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

`Route::get('getinfo.php', 'controller@function');`

You can capture query string param `name` with `$request->query('name')`.

If you use nginx, you might get "No input file specified". You need to change: `location ~ \.php$` into `location ~ index\.php$`.